# Getting strange GET error on all pages

Tags: php, html, web

Image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6spu.jpg

I'm getting this error on all my pages and I'm not sure what it could be. I took out some code bit by bit to see if there is something in the code stopping it but nothing worked so I'm thinking its a server issue. Now, yesterday I had to downgrade php to 5.3.2 to get a package installed (php5-sybase) and this caused arrays such as $array = []; to not work so then I upgraded it today to 5.4.2 and everything was working fine except for this console error.

Does anyone have a clue what the problem could be? Am I missing something server-side?

EDIT: None of my Javascript is working anymore...

Comment: Unless my eyes are bleeding, I don't see your code anywhere. Your image is just a screenshot of a file.

Comment: Are you asking us why you're getting an error without showing us _anything_ about what the error is or what your code is doing?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO that screen shot may be the least helpful thing I've seen on here in a while.

Comment: [I found the fix!!!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/aV04D.png)

Comment: What code am I supposed to show you? I told you its not code related but seems to be a server issue, if you'd give me a direction as to where to go in regards to that then we can go from there but your post is as unhelpful as my screenshot.

Comment: If your error is *code* related then you should post some code.

Comment: If it was code related I would. I tested the code by process of elimination and nothing stood out as being the cause, so my conclusion is that its a server issue. A simple php page that queries a database is showing the data but also throwing this GET error in the dev tools console. @FreshPrinceOfSO

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho Server issues go on [sf] (if you don't add code to your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on the Network tab of the Developer tools, then look for that file in the list, it should show you an error code, i.e. 500, etc.  From there you can backtrack to your web server error log.

Also look for core dumps, possible there's a bug with a library that's linked into PHP that's causing a core dump or other exit before your PHP program is finished.

Comment: Okay I went to network and under Time it says 15.03s, when I click on the file name and go to headers it says Status Code: 200 OK. Every other file (js, css, html) is loading fine except for php files. Any advice?

Comment: Do you have a URL where the problem is occuring?

Comment: Its happening on every page. Unfortunately I can't post a url for you as the website can't be accessed outside our network. Pages are taking 15 seconds to load, and once complete all JS and PHP will work and the loading will stop.